# How to bridge a wireless interface with another wireless interface (both on the same computer)?

Tags: networking, network-bridge, wireless-access-point, hostapd

Ubuntu 14.04

Basically I am trying to accomplish the following setup -

wireless internet ---> `wlan0` of Ubuntu computer "bridged to" `wlan1` of same Ubuntu computer ---> device with wifi

The reason for this setup is that the wireless internet is a WPA2 Enterprise network which my device with wifi cannot connect to. (The device with wifi also cannot connect to peer-to-peer networks or ad-hoc networks.) Also, the wireless internet source has no whitelist / blacklist and therefore there is no issue with it seeing the device's MAC address (if necessary), and no issue with it assigning an IP address to the device (if necessary). It is the device that has an issue with WPA2 Enterprise authentication.

[**EDIT** - As the device cannot successfully authenticate, the wireless internet source is NOT likely to assign an IP address to the device, and also likely to take issue with seeing the device's MAC address.]

`wlan0` is an Intel wireless chipset / interface which cannot be set to either access point mode or master mode, and therefore is used to connect to the WPA2 Enterprise internet source.

`wlan1` is to be set to access point mode.

Obviously, the "bridge" between `wlan0` and `wlan1` is not meant to be wireless, as both are on the same computer.

(1) I believe `brctl` cannot bridge a wireless interface (`wlan0`) to another wireless interface (`wlan1`).
Is this correct?

(2) If `brctl` cannot be used, can I still use `hostapd`?

(3) If `brctl` cannot be used, what should I be looking for to accomplish the setup described above?

(4) Would any of the following be a part of the solution to my problem -
(a) `dnsmasq` to serve DHCP
(b) `hostapd`
(c) static IP address (for `wlan1` ???) (for the device connected to `wlan1` ??)
(d) NAT (Network Address Translation)
(e) `iptables`
(f) IP Masquerade
(g) `sudo iw set dev wlan0 4addr on`
(h) WDS (wireless distribution system)
(i) IP Forwarding ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

> (1) I believe brctl cannot bridge a wireless interface (wlan0) to another wireless interface (wlan1). Is this correct?

The requirement here is that all interfaces must be able to send packets with any source MAC address, and receive packets with any destination MAC (not just the device's own).

Wi-Fi AP interfaces can be bridged just fine (most "wireless routers" in fact have a plain Linux bridge between AP and Ethernet). Station-mode interfaces, however, cannot. So you can bridge wlan1 but not wlan0.

There's a way around it – the "4addr" mode aka "WDS" mode, which adds an extra MAC address field to Wi-Fi frames. You can enable it via `iw`, as long as your Wi-Fi driver supports it. Once enabled, you will be able to bridge wlan0 as well.

However, for security reasons, many APs don't allow 4addr mode by default. (Some have a general toggle, some have a MAC-based whitelist.) Will it work with your university AP? Try it and see.

(Another workaround is "arpnat" – like NAT but applied to MAC addresses – but it can confuse DHCP servers, and it's not supported by regular Linux anyway. Some APs, like PicoStation, support it in station mode.)

> (2) If brctl cannot be used, can I still use hostapd?

Depends on your Wi-Fi driver. Most of them should support AP mode nowadays, but not all do. Use `iw phy0 info`, `iw phy1 info` to find out.

> (3) If brctl cannot be used, what should I be looking for to accomplish the setup described above?

The most common alternative approach would be IP NAT (masquerading) using iptables.

In some cases, regular routing (without NAT) would also work.

> (4) Would any of the following be a part of the solution to my problem
>
> (a) dnsmasq to serve DHCP (b) hostapd (c) static IP address (for wlan1 ???) (for the device connected to wlan1 ??) (d) NAT (Network Address Translation) (e) iptables (f) IP Masquerade (g) sudo iw set dev wlan0 4addr on (h) WDS (wireless distribution system) (i) IP Forwarding ?

yes, no, no, yes, maybe, maybe, what, uh, are you just throwing assorted terms here?

Comment: The internet source disconnects wlan0 when wlan0 has 4addr turned on. I believe this means that the 4addr (WDS) suggestion will not work for me. Please correct me if I am wrong. I will pursue the IP-NAT-masquerading-iptables proposal, but just a quick check - what about ebtables instead?

Comment: [Solved] iptables in place of brctl works. Issue closed.

Comment: @sean can you please expand on your iptable solution? I tried this, but with ethernet for the 2nd interface, and I can't ping beyond the hardware wireless router.

Answer (score 0):

You can bridge wireless interfaces using `brctl` without any problem:

```
brctl addbr br_name
brctl addif br_name wlan0
brctl addif br_name wlan1
```

But you will need to refer the bridge `br_name` itself, not to the separate interfaces in you network config.

Comment: You will have `br-name` interface with it's own IP, etc. If you want to configure it e.g. in `/etc/network/interfaces` you need to refer the bridge as an interface. Same with `dnsmasq`, etc.

Comment: My current config in `/etc/network/interfaces` is - 

`auto br0
iface br0 inet static
address 192.168.1.252
netmask 255.255.255.0
network 192.168.1.0
broadcast 192.168.1.255
gateway 192.168.1.254
bridge-ports wlan0 wlan1` Given that I'm specifying the details of `br0` in `/etc/network/interfaces` (see above), how do I "refer (to) the bridge as an interface"? Is the above config for `/etc/network/interfaces` ok? Will `br0` have an IP add of `192.168.1.252`, and is it ok to specify `bridge-ports wlan0 wlan1` ? Can `wlan0` receive a dynamic IP from the internet source? What is `wlan1` IP?

Comment: If you bridge two interfaces, they will not have separate IPs. The bridge will have the IP for both ports.

Comment: `wlan0` has to receive a dynamic IP when connecting to the internet source. Do I then specify `iface br0 inet dhcp` instead of `iface br0 inet static` and also remove all specific IP address numbers from `/etc/network/interfaces` ?

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: I get the error message `can't add wlan0 to bridge br0: Operation not supported`. This is regardless of whether I specify `br0` in `/etc/network/interfaces`, or `sudo brctl` to add `wlan0` to `br0`. I also tried setting up the bridge before connecting `wlan0` to the internet source (thereby receiving a dynamic IP address), as well as after (vice versa). I rebooted after each permutation (to clear the IP), but all tries result in the same error message.

Comment: Did you run `sudo brctl addbr br0` first?

Comment: Yes - I added/created the bridge first before adding the interfaces. No problem with adding `wlan1` to the bridge. From this Gentoo solution - https://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-t-833901-start-0.html , it appears that some particular file/config file has within it the line - `config_wlan0=( "null" )`, and this line must be removed from the file, but I cannot find the Ubuntu equivalent of the Gentoo file mentioned in the above URL.

Comment: Separately, for the hostapd config file, I am setting `interface=wlan1` and `bridge=br0`. Is this correct or am I supposed to specify `interface=br0`?

Comment: Found this - http://nullroute.eu.org/~grawity/journal-2011.html#post:20110826 .

Comment: The use of `sudo iw dev wlan0 set 4addr on` to counter the error message `can't add wlan0 to bridge br0: Operation not supported`, albeit unsuccessfully, necessitates this question - is a bridge (`brctl`) going to get us there? Even if the internet source accepts the enabling of `4addr`, four addresses mean that the WPA2 Enterprise source "sees" the end device - a non-authenticated device given that it is not WPA2 Enterprise capable. Instead of `brctl`, perhaps (a) setting up a route (b) ebtables (c) iptables (d) IP Forwarding (e) IP Masquerade (f) NAT? Static IP (not DHCP) for device?

Comment: @sean: It should work fine with WPA2 Enterprise, because the Wi-Fi frames have separate fields for the "radio station" MAC address and "end device" MAC address. (That's actually the reason you need 4addr, by the way.)