# Connecting wireless interface to bridge - MAC addressing

Tags: networking, network-bridge, wireless-access-point, hostapd

I've been playing around with my network settings and tried to use `hostapd` to create a WiFi hotspot based on the virtual software access point `virt1` (10.10.0.1/24). This does work flawlessly using NAT (gateway is on `wlan0` (192.168.1.1/24)).

However, if I instead try to connect `virt1` and `wlan0` using a bridge, I get the following error:

**Error: Device does not allow enslaving to a bridge.**

This error occurs when I try to connect `wlan0` to the bridge `br0` that hostapd set up automatically. Interestingly, the access point `virt1` could be connected to `br0` by hostapd without a problem.

From [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/683885/how-to-bridge-a-wireless-interface-with-another-wireless-interface-both-on-the) answer, which unfortunately I cannot follow fully, I understand that wireless APs can be bridged without a problem, but stations cannot. My  understanding is that this has something to do with the station having to send and receive frames with MAC addresses of the AP clients (but the station is limited to using its own MAC).

This brings me to my questions:

1. Is my before-mentioned understanding correct? Is MAC address restriction why I cannot enslave `wlan0` to `br0`?
2. What is the difference between connecting a wireless interface to a bridge vs. connecting a wired interface to a bridge? Wouldn't I have the same problem (frames with different MAC addresses coming out of the same interface, e.g. `eth0`) than with WiFi? What am I missing here?
3. Is this problem related with the fact that 802.11 supports Transmitter and Receiver addressing in addition to source and destination addressing?